# Can a random variable converge to different limits in different modes?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Can a random variable converge to different limits in different modes?

For example converge a.s. to a limit and converge in $L^1$ to another limit. There are many modes of convergence such as $a.s., p., weakly, etc.$

I can't find an example because maybe this is impossible, but what is the reason?

Comment: You should make your question a little more precise in several ways. First, you probably mean "a sequence of random variables converge to different limits", and second, try to be specific: pick two concrete modes of convergence. Otherwise, your question lacks content, is too broad, and therefore is unlikely to receive useful attention.

Comment: Consider any pair $\{C,C'\}$ of modes of convergence chosen from $L^p$ convergence, almost sure convergence, and convergence in probability. If $X_n\to X$ for $C$ and $X_n\to X'$ for $C'$ then $X_n\to X$ in probability and $X_n\to X'$ in probability hence, by the almost sure uniqueness of the limit in probability, $P(X=X')=1$.